# Mina Deploy "Bundle is locked to rake"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, mina

After running

```
mina deploy
```

I get this error

```
 mina deploy

-----> Creating a temporary build path
-----> Fetching new git commits
-----> Using git branch 'master'
       Cloning into '.'...
       done.
-----> Using this git commit
       root (e1bd364):
       > fixes fo rmina
-----> Symlinking shared paths
-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler
       Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
       installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
       users on this machine.
       Your Gemfile has no gem server sources. If you need gems that are not already on
       your machine, add a line like this to your Gemfile:
       source 'https://rubygems.org'
       Your bundle is locked to rake (12.0.0), but that version could not be found in
       any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that
       means the author of rake (12.0.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your
       bundle to a different version of rake (12.0.0) that hasn't been removed in order
       to install.
 !     ERROR: Deploy failed.
-----> Cleaning up build
       Unlinking current
       OK
       Connection to app.com closed.

 !     Run Error
```

If I run bundle show rake I see this

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0
```

I tried looking in app/vendor and bundler is not there. I tried using bundle install and bundle update.

Update:

I checked and source 'https:rubygems.org' is in my gemfile.

I tried running bundle install deployment

```
 bundle install --deployment
```

and ran into the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> Your Gemfile has no gem server sources. If you need gems that are not already on your machine, add a line like this to your Gemfile:
>
> ```
> source 'https://rubygems.org'
> ```

Seems like there is no gem source specified in your **`Gemfile`**

You may try adding this line at the top of your `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

and then try again

Comment: unfortunately, that did not solve the issue. I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

So the issue had to do with permissions and running as root as the error stated.

I had mina and some of the other gem folders under a different user, while deploying as root. Once I cleared up the ownership of files, and added the user as a root user, mina deployed correctly.